# Good approach to simple state management in vuejs for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue.JS and I'm creating a simple todo app, where each list has a unique id. I am iterating through all of the list to create a Vue instance:

```html
<div id="todo-list-1" class="todo-list">...</div>
<div id="todo-list-2" class="todo-list">...</div>
<div id="todo-list-3" class="todo-list">...</div>
```

```js
// main.js
document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list').forEach(list => {
   new Vue({
     el: `#${list.id}`,
     render: h => h(App)
   })
})
```

I want to create a "completed" state, which would be true when all items in a list are completed. So `#todo-list-1` has a completed state, same with `#todo-list-2` and `#todo-list-3`.

What would be a good approach to this problem? how can I handle the state for individual vue instances?

Comment: You're essentially just asking us to review a for-loop. CodeReview is about reviewing code, not Grisham novel recommendations. https://vuejsexamples.com/a-todo-list-app-using-vuejs/

Comment: thanks, I am asking for recommendation on how to approach this problem, I cant get my head around how to set a simple state for each instance.

Comment: The answer to your question is in here: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/ This kind of question does not belong on this StackExchange.

Comment: I checked the docs there already, looks like multiple store is not well supported https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/414

Answer (score 3):

I consider Vuex advanced state management, and for the sake of your simple application I, personally, would value a simpler data-centric approach.

To this end, I propose you focus on creating a single instance that can have multiple todo-lists inside it represented as components.

```html
<div id="app">
    <TodoList v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id" />
</div>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        lists: [
            {
                id: 1,
                todos: []
            },
            // ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'd need to represent your todos as a list of todo lists (with todos inside). You'll also need to ensure correct state management but JavaScripts pass-by-reference for objects will save you time here.

In order to detect if all todos are completed you could add a getter into the root instance to detect them all, or in the component to detect them per-instance.

I hope this helps set you on the right path, the best thing to do in most cases is start with your data-model as Vue is a data-centric framework.

Comment: thanks, the thing is that react has this useState hook which I used before, I need to have different instances because I am passing different api endpoints for each todo list.

Comment: If they fundamentally behave in the same way, they are the same component. If you are passing different bits of data, you can still do that. `:list="list"` will pass the entire list object to the component. You could just as easily pass config for the APIs.